# debian bluetooth bluecove java7 not working

Tags: java, bluetooth, debian, java-7, bluecove

I have a clean Debian squeeze installation and trying to get a jar app running that would communicated with the bluetooth dongle in the usb port. Hardware side all runs fine bluetooth functionality all here.
I need to run Java7 which I have installed with by downloading from oracle the jdk and using the update-alternatives to bind it into the system.

The Java app requires bluecove as a library to communicate with the system. My bluecove.jar file is in my classpath /home/app/lib I have the gpl in there and also the normal snapshot.

As I execute the app via `java -cp /home/app/lib/bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -jar myapp.jar` I have been getting the same error over and over and cannot figure it out. Its like java cannot load the bluecove.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ|com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZDBus not available
        at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.loadStackClass(BlueCoveImpl.java:356)
        at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:447)
        at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$500(BlueCoveImpl.java:69)
        at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:1044)
```

Anyone seen this? thanks!

Comment: Anyone have a comment here. My bluetooth is running fine. It just looks like my classpath is being ignored. The jars are not being loaded. Has anyone ran bluecove with Java7

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/downloads

download 'bluecove-2.1.0.jar' and 'bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar' both.
linux require a bluecove-gpl jar file too.

and then export or use -cp in runtime

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:(/your bluecove jar location)
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:(/your bluecove gpl jar location)
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to do what is described here and after a few attempts it finally worked after recompiling most. No clue why this is required but it works:

https://sites.google.com/site/opengaragedoor1/home/stages/raspberry-pi